# Drawing a line graph with dynamic plotting in ios

Tags: ios, graphics

I am going to develop an app which takes current and voltage as input values. I need to display certain values which are generated infinite times on applying certain calculations on those inputs in a graph. I have searched many web pages but I am not able to understand the real facts. Is there any way to plot line graph with plotting of points dynamically in iOS?

Comment: check this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724887/ios-chart-libraries) for plotting libraries

Comment: @ tkanzakic thanks.Let me go through it